# Проверка существования значения многомерного массива

Tags: массивы, php

Как проверить что ключ

```
$parts_dump[19][5]
```

существует и в нем есть что?

Как вообще происходит проверка существования ключей в многомерных массивах?

Comment: взгляните на мой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576671/php-testing-for-existence-of-a-cell-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

Можно все выкрутить рекурсивной функцией если вложенность может быть неопределенной, а если у Вас вложенность многомерного массива только на 2 уровня, тогда можно воспользоватся функцией is_array().

Answer (score 0):

Как написал выше **Ivan Tibezh**:
<pre>
if ( isset ( $parts_dump['19']['5'] ) ) echo 'существует' else 'не существует';
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Если известны ключи:

`if ( isset($parts_dump[19][5]) ) {...}  // проверка на сущестование ключа
 if ( !empty($parts_dump[19][5]) ) {...} // проверка на пустоту ключа`

Если не известны ключи:

```
foreach ($parts_dump as $key => $part) {
    foreach ($part as $key_ => $part_) {

        if ( isset($part_[$key][$key_]) ) {...}  // проверка на сущестование ключа
        if ( !empty($part_[$key][$key_]) ) {...} // проверка на пустоту ключа`

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = 19;
$col = 5;

// нужно проверить существование первого уровня массива. 
// если не проверить, а $parts_dump[19] пустой - будет ошибка.
if (isset($parts_dump[$row] and isset($parts_dump[$row][$col])) {
    echo $parts_dump[$row][$col];
}
```